# Application does not do anything when inserting values to MYSQL using Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am Trying to develop and android application that can insert values in my mySQL database using an android application. But I not able to get the values to be stored in to the database. I have followed a few tutorials and I tried to do it but till now have had no luck.

Could some one let me know that the code i have used is correct.

The have used the below code to insert values the values into my MYSQL database

```
package com.example.androidsql.mysqlsample01activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MysqlSample01Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextAdd;
   private EditText editDepartment;



    private static final String TAG = "MysqlSample01Activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mysql_sample01);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
        editDepartment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Department);

    }

    public void insert(View view){
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();
        String dept = editDepartment.getText().toString();

        insertToDatabase(name,add,dept);
    }

    private void insertToDatabase(String name, String add,String dept){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                try
                {
                    posttext ();
                }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, add);
    }


       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
       private void posttext ()
       {


           try {


               String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
               String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();
               String dept = editDepartment.getText().toString();

               // adding Data
               List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",add));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("depart",dept));


               HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

               HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.5/nfcams/insertingCustodian.php");

               httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


               // execute HTTP POST request
               HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

               //is = entity.getContent();
               if (entity != null) {

                   String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity).trim();
                   Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + responseStr);

                   // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
               }

           } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

               e.printStackTrace();

           } catch (IOException e) {

               e.printStackTrace();

           }





       }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mysql_sample01, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The manifest  code is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidsql.mysqlsample01activity" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name=".MysqlSample01Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The layout code is stated below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MysqlSample01Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewResult"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextAddress"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextName" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="insert"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Department"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextAddress"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The PHP code I have used

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$Design = $_POST['address'];
$Depart = $_POST['depart'];


//$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO `custodian` (`Name`, `Design`, `Depart`) VALUES ('$name', '$Design', '$Depart')";

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO store_users(`CustName`, `CustDesign`,`CustDepart`) VALUES ('$Custname', '$CustDesign','$CustDepart')";

$response = array();

if(mysqli_query($con,$sqlinsert)) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } 


  mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: You have some severe SQL injection issues in this code, which should be fixed prior to going live.

Comment: @MikeKeepsOnShine: I think that edit is too severe. If someone wishes to try compiling this, they will need all those `import`s.

Comment: Where are you getting errors? Is the PHP script called? If not try adding some Logging stuff to find out where is the problem.

Comment: @jacktech24 I have checked the php script and it is working fine but the java code does not seem to pass values to the php script. How do i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you to use some library for networking like Ion (https://github.com/koush/ion) or Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) depends on what is more suitable for you. These libs make it more easy for you to do networking without pain. For example, what you are trying to do, with Ion would look like this:

```android
public void insert(View view) {
    String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
    String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();
    String dept = editDepartment.getText().toString();

    Ion.with(this)
            .load("http://192.168.2.5/nfcams/insertingCustodian.php")
            .setBodyParameter("name", name)
            .setBodyParameter("address", add)
            .setBodyParameter("depart", dept)
            .asString()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Response: " + result);
                }
            });
}
```

Tell me if it helped you or not. I can also post you how it should look like using your previous method, but I don't see any errors there on first look.

Comment: Thankx It works now I have used the library's you had mentioned in the same method. i case i want to insert images or Date on the database do i have to use the same steps as you have mentioned or do i need to do some changes to it.

Comment: @NikhilRcop if you want to upload images or files see https://github.com/koush/ion it's described there